# Give a combinatorial argument to evaluate sum $\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n }{k}\binom{m}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{k}^{n}\binom{n }{k}\binom{m}{k}$$

I'm not really sure how a combinatorial argument would help me evaluate this?
I was thinking maybe I'm adding up all the ways that you could divide a group of n+m people into 2 groups of size k?

I'm tempted to just plug in the fact that $$\binom{n}{k} =\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$but that's not really a combinatorial argument, right?

Answer (score 1):

Choose $k$ things from $n$ and choose $m-k$ things from $m$ ($k$ ranges over $0$ to $\min(n,m)$) ... This is the same as choosing $m$ things from $n+m$.

Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\min(n,m)}\binom{n }{k}\binom{m}{k} = \binom{n+m}{m}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Would that be the entire argument though, or is that just the intuition to get me started?

Comment: This will do as the entire argument.

Comment: I don't need to add anything else to consider it a sum?

Comment: Maybe mention 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{m}{m-k} = \binom{m}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*} It is clear that is a sum as $k$ ranges over it's values.